# Multi-monitor: one or the other monitor goes black

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I have two monitors hooked to a GTX-960. One is connected via DVI and the other via DP. This is a System76 Leopard Extreme desktop. I'm using the proprietary Nvidia "tested" drivers. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Quite often (~50% of the time) when I arrive in the morning one or the other monitor is black (in sleep mode, has no signal). Sometimes re-plugging the monitor works, but other times only a reboot fixes the problem. Sometimes both monitors are black, re-plugging doesn't help and I need to power-button reboot the system.

I have my system set to never sleep. I have my screen set to "turn off when inactive: never".

I've tried the Xorg drivers and DP doesn't work at all in that case. I've tried the "untested" drivers with the same result.

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but it's a workaround: when I'm in this state, toggling between console mode and back to graphical mode (ctrl-alt-f1 and ctrl-alt-f7) kicks the monitor out of sleep and fixes the problem.